# Trigonometry issue - Create a PointF using an angle

Tags: c#, .net, trigonometry

I have been scratching my head on this for quite a while now. Guess I should have paid more attention in the trigonometry math classes when I was younger but here we go:

I have an angle and a point. I then want to put a second point in the direction of the angle, 200 units away from the first point. I use Atan2 to get the angle, then cos and sin to get the third point. But... I think something goes wrong when calculating the Sin for p3.Y.

EDIT: To clarify, I removed p2 and used the angle directly:

```
        PointF p1 = new PointF(20, 20);
        double angle = 1.3034851559678624f;

        //Create a new PointF in the same direction, 200 pixels away from p1
        //{ X = 199,9482, Y = 4,549629 }
        PointF p3 = new PointF
        {
            X = (float)(Math.Cos(Math.PI * angle / 180.0) * 200),
            Y = (float)(Math.Sin(Math.PI * angle / 180.0) * 200)
        };

        //This is where I would expect 1.3034851559678624 as the first angle 
        //but I get -4.9073849244837184
        double angle2 = Math.Atan2(p3.Y - p1.Y, p3.X - p1.X) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Here is a visual representation of the values above. The green line is the first angle.

[image: Visual overview]

Comment: Shouldn't that final calculation reference the `X` values at some point?

Comment: don't take my word for it, but i believe you should express those angles in radians.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Where would I use the X point?

Comment: @NikoDrašković - Yes, perhaps that would simplify but in my final code, I will be given an angle in degree's so I need to understand how to convert correctly back and forth at least.

Comment: Is p3 supposed to be on the line defined by p1-p2 ?  I'm not very good at reading code or minds (!) but your description of the problem seems to be at variance with your code.  If p3 is not supposed to be on that line what do you mean by 'in between' ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - Yes, p3 is supposed to be right on the green line.

Comment: `Math.Atan2(p3.Y - p1.Y, p3.Y - p1.Y)` - if this was going to resemble the other lines using `Atan2`, I'd have expected the second calculation to use `X` rather than `Y`...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Ah yes, typo which I corrected now. Didn't solve the main issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that you don't calculate `p3` relative to `p1`.  You need to add `p1.X` and `p1.Y` to the coordinates of `p3`:

```
PointF p3 = new PointF
{
    X = p1.X + (float)(Math.Cos(Math.PI * angle / 180.0) * 200),
    Y = p1.Y + (float)(Math.Sin(Math.PI * angle / 180.0) * 200)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if p3 is supposed to be on the line p1-p2 you don't need to use any trigonometry at all.  You can find the coordinates of p3 directly from those of p1 and p2.  Suppose the distance between p1 and p2 is 1000 units.  Then the location of p3, 200 units from p1 is:

```
{p1.x+(p2.x-p1.x)*(200/1000),p1.y+(p2.y-p1.y)*(200/1000)}
```

If the distance between the two points is not 1000 (which of course it won't be), replace that value by the [Euclidean Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between them.

If you still want the slope of the line you calculate the ratio

```
(p2.y-p1.y)/(p2.x-p1.x)
```

which gives you the slope as a single number, where 1 represents the line which passes through the origin at a `+45deg` angle.  A little fiddling around will turn the slope into the angle, be careful when the line is vertical, ie where the denominator of the ratio is 0.

Comment: Yes, the issue is that in my final code, I will only be given an angle and a PointF. Then I will need to work out how to create a second PointF 200 units away.

Comment: @BlueVoodo: now I find your question even more confusing.  Why don't you edit it to state clearly what your requirement is ?  Something like: Given a 2D point and an {angle, distance}, compute the {x,y} coordinates of a 2nd point at that remove from the first point.  I can't see why you have got a 3rd point involved at all.  you've certainly confused me, probably confused yourself too.  I'll come back and have another look after you've edited the question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited my comment for furhter clarification. I only used p2 to easilly get an angle and to be able to visually represent it in my image.

Comment: @BlueVoodoo: edit your question radically, I think that p2 is completely redundant and misleading to readers of the question.

Comment: And now you have the answer to the question you wanted to ask all along !

Answer (score 0):

You did not have to use atan to get the angle and then calc sin/cos.
You can get sin and cos direct from coordinates of points.

```
cos = (p2.x - p1.x)/length
sin = (p2.y - p1.y)/length
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_%28geometry%29

Comment: Thanks but in my final code, I will not only have the angle and the first point so I need to understand how to make this work.

Comment: I guess mistake in atan representation. atan its not full representation of angle. look for range of values atan.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: I think you miss quarter of flat when get atan.

Comment: Legt me read up on this a bit more. When you say "quarter of flat", you mean what exactly? How would I modify my code to adjust?